# How do I find a meagre dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

How do I find $M \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ which is meagre and dense?

If I understand the definitions correctly, I need  $$M=\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k, \quad {\overline M}=\mathbb{R}^2.$$

Trying $M=\mathbb{Q}^2$ seems to work, $A_k$ being a singleton set is rare in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for each $k$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes: every countable subset of $\Bbb R^2$ is meagre, and $\Bbb Q^2$ is also dense.

Comment: what is meager? (for my information)

Comment: @pGroups A subset $M$ of a metric space $X$ is meager if it is the countable union of rare sets in $X$. While a subset of $X$ is rare when its closure has no interior points.

Comment: @pGroups: In topology a [meagre set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set) is also said to be *first category*, the union of countably many nowhere dense sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ the singleton $\{x\}$ is closed and has empty interior, so it is rare. As $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is the countable union of singletons and dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$, your example is correct.